# Akka Streams override KillSwitch

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have the following Graph:

```scala
case class FlowFactory() {

  val reactiveConnection = ???
  val serviceRabbitConnection = ???

  val switch = KillSwitches.single[Routed]

  val stream: RunnableGraph[UniqueKillSwitch] = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(switch) { implicit builder: GraphDSL.Builder[UniqueKillSwitch] => sw =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val in = builder.add(Source.fromPublisher(reactiveConnection.consume(???)))
    val context = builder.add(contextFlow(serviceRabbitConnection))
    val inflate = builder.add(inflateFlow())
    val compute = builder.add(computeFlow())
    val out = builder.add(Sink.fromSubscriber(reactiveConnection.publish()))

    in ~> context ~> inflate ~> compute ~> sw ~> out

    ClosedShape
  })

  val killSwitch = stream.run()

  killSwitch.shutdown()

}
```

When I shutdown the stream, I also need to kill the following connections : `reactiveConnection` and `serviceRabbitConnection`. 
How do I achieve that, is there a easy way to override `KillSwitch`'s `shutdown()` method? 
Is there a method that is called when the stream is closed?, like `onComplete()` or `onClose()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform your callback *inside the stream*, by attaching an additional sink (`Sink.onComplete`).

```
  val sink1 = Sink.fromSubscriber(reactiveConnection.publish())
  val sink2 = Sink.onComplete{
    case Success(_) ⇒ println("success!")
    case Failure(e) ⇒ println(s"failure - $e")
  }

  val out = builder.add(Sink.combine(sink1, sink2)(Broadcast(_)))
```